# How to create Promise, for modal confirm dialog

Tags: javascript, angular, promise

I am actually using Angular 2, but I found a solution, but it seems to me like it is just an workaround. And it isn't fully working right now.

I created an service, that can be injected anywhere, and an component, that sits at root component template.

```js
class DialogService {
    output: Subject<DialogEvent>

    constructor(){
        this.output = new Subject()
    }

    ask(question = 'Are you sure?', accept = 'Ok', cancel = 'Cancel') {
        var input = new Subject()
        this.output.next({question, cancel, accept, input})
        return input.toPromise()
    }
}
```

```js
class DialogComponent {
    private output: Subject<boolean>
    texts: DialogEvent = {}

    constructor(private dialogService: DialogService) {
        this.dialogService.output.subscribe(event => {
            this.texts = event
            this.output = event.input
            this.show()
        })
    }

    cancel() {
        this.output.next(false)
        this.hide()
    }

    accept() {
        this.output.next(true)
        this.hide()
    }
}
```

This setup works to the point, that it will open on ask in service, and close, with correct function (accept, or cancel), but the promise is not created, or fired.

Anyway, if there is a better way to make this work, I al 100% for it.

Comment: what is that you are trying to achieve?? **DialogService** what is the key purpose of having a confirm dialog as a service?

Comment: So it can be called from anywhere. I took inspiration from https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html, as they made a DialogService too

Comment: This is not advisable and it will be singleton and you need to be very careful while handling this

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't understand what you are saying...

Comment: Of course, it won't fire, you should call `.complete()` on observer to make a promise completed. What kind of pattern is it? If you want an observer and an observable in one, use a subject. If you're using observables, why a promise is there?

Comment: So it works when it get used multiple times... I am not good at rxjs. I was happy to get this going... How would it look with Subject?

Comment: Subject is an object that has both .subscribe and .next methods. No need to have separate `observer` and `observable`. It's just `input = new Subject()` (not sure what `output` is for).

Comment: Output is for opening dialogue component, while input is for recieving. The subject is actually working, thank you. (If you want me to accept your answer please type it down)

Comment: How does this line compile? `this.dialogService.input.next(false)` There is no "next" method on `input`

Comment: @pixelbits i did some post changes... My bad

Comment: Observable should be private, Observer should be public, calling `next` should only happen inside of the service.

Comment: @pixelbits I made few changes based on finding from Aravind.